# Is there any way to add extra parameters in sails middleware?

Tags: express, sails.js, middleware

We have a sails application behind azure authentication which passes a header with email address.

I need to use this email address as a param in my all controllers.

I am trying to add below in my sails http.js middleware. But I am not receiving the param as expected in controller.

```
aadAppendUser: function (req, res, next) { //Azure Active Directory append User Email
        sails.log("Requested :: ", req.method, req.url);
        const emailHeader = 'x-ms-client-principal-name';
        req.param.userMail = req.headers[emailHeader];
        sails.log("userMail :: ", req.param.userMail);
        // sails.log('All Params', req.allParams());
        return next();
    }
```

I also added it to the order in http.js file.

Please suggest me if there is any other way to achieve this.

Comment: did you tried checking just `req.headers`?

Comment: I am getting it in headers. But I need this as a req.param which I need to pass to another API.

Comment: `req.params` is the key on which parameter exists, and `req.param` is the function to access these parameters. please try setting on `req.params`.

Answer (score 0):

`req.params` is the key on which parameter exists, and `req.param` is the function to access these parameters.

please try setting on `req.params`.

Moreover `req.param` is now deprecated

`req.params`: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.params

`req.param`: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.param